# Web Display Not Change To Latest Data Until Need to Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

i try to make a code to fetch transaction data from Stellar Horizon as an API. Im successfully fetch and display the data, but it just static. The web need to refresh to display latest transaction. I want my web to automatically change to display latest transaction occurs on Stellar network without need to refresh web page. I try by using AJAX. But still not works right now. Please help. Below is my code :

in PHP file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Stellar Transaction Fetcher
 * Plugin URI: https://your-plugin-url.com/
 * Description: Fetches live transaction data for a Stellar account using the Horizon API.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Your Name
 * Author URI: https://your-website.com/
 */

/**
 * Enqueue necessary scripts and styles.
 */
function stellar_transaction_fetcher_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue custom CSS or JavaScript files if needed
    wp_enqueue_style('stellar-transaction-fetcher', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('stellar-transaction-fetcher', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);

    // Pass the Horizon API endpoint and account to JavaScript
    wp_localize_script('stellar-transaction-fetcher', 'stellarFetcher', array(
        'apiEndpoint' => 'https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/',
        'account' => 'YOUR_STELLAR_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY'
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stellar_transaction_fetcher_enqueue_scripts');

/**
 * Display the latest Stellar transaction for a given account.
 *
 * @param string $account The Stellar account public key.
 */
function display_latest_stellar_transaction($account) {
    // Fetch the latest transaction
    $transaction = fetch_latest_stellar_transaction($account);

    if (is_wp_error($transaction)) {
        // Handle error
        $error_message = $transaction->get_error_message();
        echo 'Error: ' . $error_message;
    } else {
        // Display the transaction
        echo '<ul>';

        // Access transaction properties
        $transaction_hash = $transaction['transaction_hash'];
        $transaction_date = $transaction['created_at'];
        $from = isset($transaction['from']) ? $transaction['from'] : '-';
        $to = isset($transaction['to']) ? $transaction['to'] : '-';
        $asset_type = isset($transaction['asset_type']) ? $transaction['asset_type'] : '-';
        $asset_code = isset($transaction['asset_code']) ? $transaction['asset_code'] : '-';
        $amount = isset($transaction['amount']) ? $transaction['amount'] : '-';
        $transaction_link = isset($transaction['_links']['transaction']['href']) ? $transaction['_links']['transaction']['href'] : '';

        // Fetch memo data
        $memo = fetch_memo_data($transaction_link);

        // Display transaction details
        echo '<li>';
        echo 'From: ' . $from . '<br>';
        echo 'To: ' . $to . '<br>';
        echo 'Asset Type: ' . $asset_type . '<br>';
        echo 'Asset Code: ' . $asset_code . '<br>';
        echo 'Amount: ' . $amount . '<br>';
        echo 'Memo: ' . $memo . '<br>';
        echo 'Transaction Hash: ' . $transaction_hash . '<br>';
        echo 'Transaction Date: ' . $transaction_date . '<br>';
        echo '</li>';

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

/**
 * Fetches the latest transaction for a Stellar account using the Horizon API.
 *
 * @param string $account The Stellar account public key.
 * @return array|WP_Error An array containing the transaction data or WP_Error on failure.
 */
function fetch_latest_stellar_transaction($account) {
    // Set Horizon API endpoint and account public key
    $api_endpoint = 'https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/' . $account . '/payments?order=desc&limit=1';

    // Prepare the API request
    $request_args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
    );

    // Make the API request
    $response = wp_remote_get($api_endpoint, $request_args);

    // Check for API request errors
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Parse the API response
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    // Check for successful API response
    if ($response_code === 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response_body, true);

        // Extract transaction data from the response
        $transaction = isset($data['_embedded']['records'][0]) ? $data['_embedded']['records'][0] : array();

        return $transaction;
    } else {
        // Handle API response errors
        return new WP_Error(
            'stellar_api_error',
            'Failed to fetch Stellar transaction data. Error: ' . $response_code
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Fetches memo data for a Stellar transaction using the Horizon API.
 *
 * @param string $transactionLink The link to the Stellar transaction.
 * @return string|WP_Error The memo data or WP_Error on failure.
 */
function fetch_memo_data($transactionLink) {
    // Make the API request
    $response = wp_remote_get($transactionLink);

    // Check for API request errors
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Parse the API response
    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    // Check for successful API response
    if ($response_code === 200) {
        $data = json_decode($response_body, true);
        $memo = isset($data['memo']) ? $data['memo'] : '';

        return $memo;
    } else {
        // Handle API response errors
        return new WP_Error(
            'stellar_api_error',
            'Failed to fetch Stellar memo data. Error: ' . $response_code
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Shortcode handler for displaying the latest Stellar transaction.
 *
 * @param array $atts Shortcode attributes.
 * @return string Generated output for the shortcode.
 */
function stellar_latest_transaction_shortcode($atts) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'account' => '',
    ), $atts);

    // Validate the account attribute
    $account = sanitize_text_field($atts['account']);

    if (empty($account)) {
        return 'Please provide a valid Stellar account public key.';
    }

    // Display the latest transaction
    ob_start();
    display_latest_stellar_transaction($account);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('stellar_latest_transaction', 'stellar_latest_transaction_shortcode');
```

In JS File :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Function to fetch the latest transaction data using AJAX
    function fetchLatestTransaction() {
        $.ajax({
            url: stellarFetcher.apiEndpoint + stellarFetcher.account + '/payments?order=desc&limit=1',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response._embedded && response._embedded.records && response._embedded.records.length > 0) {
                    var transaction = response._embedded.records[0];
                    updateTransactionDetails(transaction);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }

    // Function to update the transaction details on the webpage
    function updateTransactionDetails(transaction) {
        var transactionHash = transaction.transaction_hash;
        var transactionDate = transaction.created_at;
        var from = transaction.from ? transaction.from : '-';
        var to = transaction.to ? transaction.to : '-';
        var assetType = transaction.asset_type ? transaction.asset_type : '-';
        var assetCode = transaction.asset_code ? transaction.asset_code : '-';
        var amount = transaction.amount ? transaction.amount : '-';
        var transactionLink = transaction._links.transaction.href;

        // Fetch memo data using AJAX
        fetchMemoData(transactionLink, function(memo) {
            // Update transaction details dynamically
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').html('');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('<li>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('From: ' + from + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('To: ' + to + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Asset Type: ' + assetType + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Asset Code: ' + assetCode + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Amount: ' + amount + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Memo: ' + memo + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Transaction Hash: ' + transactionHash + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('Transaction Date: ' + transactionDate + '<br>');
            $('.stellar-transaction-details').append('</li>');
        });
    }

    // Function to fetch memo data using AJAX
    function fetchMemoData(transactionLink, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: transactionLink,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                var memo = response.memo ? response.memo : '';
                callback(memo);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);
            }
        });
    }

    // Fetch the latest transaction on page load
    fetchLatestTransaction();

    // Fetch the latest transaction every 10 seconds
    setInterval(fetchLatestTransaction, 10000);
});
```

Someone please help me to fix this problem as i try so many days but cannot solve this problem. I dont know where to fix this to make sure it can show latest transaction without need to refresh webpage or even without need to open web as i try to send the data to other platform like telegram.